# Any problems installing Craft on CentOS with SELinux enabled?

Tags: install

Seriously considering installing Craft on CentOS w/SELinux.  I currently have it running on Ubuntu.  Anyone have any problems with that type of install?

thanks,

Chip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone with more CentOS experience will probably want to chime in—like you I'm more familiar with Debian/Ubuntu—but I can't imagine it wouldn't work, assuming you configure SELinux correctly and you're [using](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/15849/craft-cms-needs-mysql-510-or-higher-to-run) at least CentOS 6, preferably the latest.

Basically, SELinux is an kernel level gatekeeper, preventing or allowing certain processes from reading/writing to parts of the file system.

In terms of how that affects Craft, you'll need to make sure it knows that Apache/PHP is allowed to write to `/craft/app`, `craft/config` and `craft/storage` and whatever upload directories you have setup.

Just perusing the SELinux docs and problems people have had with Yii and WordPress, assuming your Craft install is at `/var/www/craft/` running something like:

```
cd /var/www/craft/
chcon -R -v -t public_content_rw_t app/ config/ storage/
```

... should open up the permissions. There's more to it than that obviously.

If you run PHP as an [FPM pool/CGI](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=288728), as I do, that's [going to affect permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/596790/selinux-label-for-php-fpm-sockets) as well.

[This article](http://edvoncken.net/2010/06/configuring-selinux-for-wordpress/) is based around setting up permissions for WordPress but it's still applicable for Craft.

Comment: We are running Craft on CentOS 6 and 7 without issues, you only have to get a newer version of PHP (than the one available from the default repos) from EPEL or Webtatic. I think CentOS 7 defaults to 5.4 which might be too old for Craft 3. No experience with SELinux though.

Comment: @megatrond: Thanks for that!  Craft 3 is going to require PHP 5.4 (http://buildwithcraft.com/3/docs/installing-and-updating) so you're right, if this is a new box, you might as well head straight to the latest version. Another hurdle there is it looks like CentOS 7 officially comes with MariaDB instead of MySQL unless you use another repo to get it.

Comment: We're using the default MariaDB without issues.

Comment: I have been doing a related project with CentOS and SELinux and I am starting to like the addition MAC along with the DAC, but, I just didn't want to jump into something that will cause me a problem.  I may run both systems for a bit and see if I can get Craft fully running in the more secure environment. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working out!